Airflow on Docker can't connect to Spark master for Submit Spark Job
I want to use SparkSubmitOperator of airflow to Submit spark job to be processed at Spark Cluster, but the problem encountered is that airflow cannot connect to spark master.
I use the following tools.

I work on only one computer.
Run Airflow on Docker Container.
Run Spark by cmd on window
This is the command in cmd that I use: run spark master bin\spark-class2.cmd org.apache.spark.deploy.master.Master

version

Docker Engine : 25.0.3
Airflow : 2.9.0
Spark : spark-3.5.1-bin-hadoop3
Windows 11

Spark WebUIe
Airflow Connection
Airflow Log Errorenter
Please guide me to solve this problem. I want to create Spark Cluster and Airflow On Premise.
